# Jquery tabs not selectable

Tags: macos, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to use jquery-ui tabs with my rails application. The tabs are visible but not selectable.

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><%=link_to "Home", "#" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "About", :controller=>"home", :action=>"about" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Pastors", "#" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Staff", "#" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Ministries", "#" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Events", "#" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Youth", "#" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Services", "#" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Media", "#" %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Contact Us", "#" %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<link type="text/css" href="pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#navigation").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included the jquery and jquery-ui js files? Are you getting any Javascript errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you still have to specify how the tabs() function is going to load the data for each tab. The jQuery UI has information here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/.

You might do something like jQuery gives in [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html) if you want to use ajax:

```
$( "#navigation" ).tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
            $( anchor.hash ).html(
                "Couldn't load this tab." );
        }
    }
});
```

I apologize if this is unhelpful or incorrect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you also using jquery-tools?

There is a namespace collision between the two libraries in that tabs are defined in both.

I solved this by going to the jqueryui/downloads link and creating a custom jquery-ui file without the tabs component.